# Что такое double rounding error (ошибка двойного округления)?

Tags: ieee-754

Слышал, что при работе с числами с плавающей запятой возможна так называемая ошибка двойного (повторного) округления (double rounding error), особенно когда имеют место переходы от одинарной точности (float) к двойной (double) и наоборот. Как это понимать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эта ошибка мало известна в среде обычных профессиональных программистов, потому что возникает она крайне редко, да и то в задачах с особой спецификой. Почти наверняка вы никогда её не встретите. Но знать о ней нужно хотя бы для общего развития и повышения культуры работы с арифметикой с плавающей запятой.

## В чём суть ошибки?

Ошибка двойного округления иногда возникает в тех случаях, когда вместо одного округления выполняется два последующих друг за другом округления. Рассмотрим пример в десятичной системе счисления. У нас есть число `1,34999`. Если мы сразу округлим его до одного знака после десятичной запятой, то получим `1,3`. Но если сначала округлить до двух знаков, а потом до одного, то получим `1,35`, а затем `1,4`. Как мы видим, результаты получились разными, причём существенно!

## Как это связано с моей программой?

В вашей программе могут быть, как минимум три (больше я просто не знаю) места, где может быть ошибка двойного округления.

1. Вы используете тип данных `double` размером 64 бита, но на вашем компьютере нет команд, которые работают с `double` (или компилятор их не поддерживает), а есть только сопроцессор x87. Таким образом, любая операция с `double` выглядит так: происходит расширение типа с 64-х до 80-ти битов, затем, собственно, необходимые вычисления, в которых результат округляется до 63-х битов дробной части мантиссы (такова структура 80-битового числа с плавающей запятой), а затем происходит второе округление до 52-х битов дробной части мантиссы в `double`.

Пример программы. Числа для кода я позаимствовал у @Mark Dickinson из англоязычного SO. Вы знаете, что `long double` размером 80 битов в настоящий момент не поддерживается (например, в VC++ точно), а заменяется на обычный `double`. Поэтому пример работать не будет, если не указать специальную опцию компилятора, которая заставит его работать через x87. У каждого компилятора своя такая опция (если вообще есть).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  double a = 1e16 + 2.9999, b;
  long double x = 1e16L, y = 2.9999L;
  b = (double)(x+y);
  printf ("a = %16.0lf, b = %16.0lf\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Программа выдаст два разных целых числа: `10000000000000002` и `10000000000000004`, показывая, тем самым, разницу, возникшую в результате двойного округления.

2. Вы используете функции, которые созданы специально для `double`, но подаёте им на вход числа `float`. Скажем, есть функция `sqrt` для `double`. Если передать ей на вход число `float`, то произойдёт расширение его до `double`, затем функция вычислит результат с округлением, а затем выполнится второе округление, если вы присваиваете результат обратно во `float`. К сожалению, каких-то реальных примеров подобной ошибки мне отыскать не удалось, но чисто теоретически любая подмена `float` на `double` и обратно может дать ошибку двойного округления. Это будет хорошо видно на последнем, самом любопытном примере.
3. Данное наблюдение я подсмотрел в статье “[Double Rounding Errors in Floating-Point Conversions](http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/)”, но сделал свой собственный пример. Общий смысл таков, что константа может быть неверно преобразована в бинарный формат на этапе компиляции, если произойдёт двойное округление. Это может произойти когда когда вы забыли суффикс `f` для чисел типа `float` или если пользуетесь VC++ любой версии.

Для демонстрации за основу будет взято число 1+2<sup>-23</sup>+2<sup>-24</sup>-2<sup>-54</sup>. Оно равно `1.000000178813934270660723768742172978818416595458984375`. Это число интересно тем, что в двоичном формате оно равно

1,00000000000000000000001**0**1111111111111111111111111111**11**<sub>(2)</sub>

Полужирным шрифтом я отметил биты 24 и 53-54. Если читатель не знаком с правилами округления чисел в формате IEEE-754, то ему придётся сначала их изучить. Например, [здесь](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/rounding-modes/). Если мы хотим перевести данное число в формат `float`, то никаких проблем нет: 24-й бит равен нулю, а значит округление до 23-х бит, необходимых `float`, произойдёт вниз без вопросов. Получим число `1,00000000000000000000001`, что в формате IEEE-754 будет иметь вид `0x3f800001`. Если же мы сначала приводим число к типу `double`, то округление до 52-х бит сначала произойдёт вверх, и мы получим `1,0000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000`, а затем, из-за того, что 23-й и 24-й биты теперь равны `1`, в результате второго округления до `float` получим `1,00000000000000000000010` (снова округление произошло вверх), что в шестнадцатеричной записи будет иметь вид `0x3f800002`. Как видно, мы получили два разных числа.

Рассмотрим демонстрационный код (не плюйтесь, что в коде есть грязные трюки, здесь я хочу просто и без хитростей показать биты числа):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

int main (void) {
  float a, b;
  double c;
  a = 1.000000178813934270660723768742172978818416595458984375f;
  b = 1.000000178813934270660723768742172978818416595458984375;
  c = 1.000000178813934270660723768742172978818416595458984375;
  printf ("a = %08x, b = %08x, c = %016llx\n", *(u32*)&a, *(u32*)&b, *(u64*)&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Здесь переменная `a` инициализируется правильно, мы используем суффикс `f`, инициализация переменной `b` происходит так, будто программист забыл про суффикс `f` (к счастью, многие компиляторы ему об этом напомнят), поэтому здесь произойдёт двойное округление (сначала константа превратиться в `double`, а затем будет присвоена к `float`), а переменная `c` здесь просто так, для демонстрации промежуточного округления в `double`. Функция `printf` выводит шестнадцатеричный код всех трёх переменных. Компилятор Tiny C выдаёт верный ответ:

```
a = 3f800001, b = 3f800002, c = 3ff0000030000000
```

Такой же точно ответ выдали Intel C 15 и Clang.

Компилятор VC 2015 выдал

```
a = 3f800002, b = 3f800002, c = 3ff0000030000000
```

Это значит, что он **ИГНОРИРУЕТ** суффикс `f`, если он установлен, и в любом случае приводит результат сначала к `double`, а потом к `float`, если нужно. По-хорошему, разработчики компилятора заработали этим сильный удар линейкой по пальцам.

Копилятор GCC из MinGW выдал также неверный ответ

```
a = 3f800001, b = 3f800001, c = 3ff0000030000000
```

То есть с точки зрения исходного желания программиста ответ верный (и здесь он молодец, что угадал это желание), но с точки зрения Стандарта - нет.

## Что же теперь делать?

Повышайте культуру работы с числами с плавающей запятой, никогда не делайте необоснованного расширения типа данных с тем, чтобы потом вернуться обратно. Да, зачастую это оправдано, но оправдание должно быть не чисто интуитивным, а строго доказанным.

Будьте осторожны, и да минуют вас ошибки двойного округления.

Comment: Ого, капитальный ответ! По поводу промежуточных вычислений в более «длинном» типе данных, насколько мне помнится, это явно разрешено стандартом.

Comment: @VladD, тут важно не сколько разрешено или нет, сколько сам факт возможной ошибки там, где программист её меньше всего ожидал увидеть.