# Операции над double с точностью до 6 знаков

Tags: c++, c, double

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо складывать числа с плавающей точкой с точностью 6 знаков после запятой. Пробовал такие варианты:

```
double calcFreqLBand(double freqReal)
{
    int convertor = 10000;
    double lFreq;
    lFreq=freqReal - (double)convertor;

    return lFreq;
}

double calcFreqLBand(double freqReal)
{
    int convertor = 10000;
    double lFreq;

    quint64 freqRealHz=freqReal*1000000;
    quint64 convFreqHz=convertor*1000000;

    quint64 delta =freqRealHz - convFreqHz;
    lFreq = (double)delta/1000000.0;

    return lFreq;
}
```

На вход даю 11920.248666f, ожидаю получить 1920.248666, но получаю допустим 1920.249023 (значения имеют некое отклонение, но не равны ожидаемому). Есть ли варианты исправить ситуацию. Использую QT 5.4, mingw.

Comment: Уберите суффикс `f` в своём числе, которые вы туда передаёте. Если не поможет, буду думать дальше. Дело в том, что `f` значит `float`, а у вас `double`, отсюда и потери.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить такой код:

```
cout << setprecision(12) << 11920.248666f << endl;
cout << setprecision(12) << 11920.248666 << endl;
```

вы получите

```
11920.2490234
11920.248666
```

Дело в том, что точность `float` недостаточна для представления вашего числа, и оно превращается  в ближайшее *представимое* типом `float` значение...

Comment: В связи с суффиксом `f` также рекомендую вопрос [Что такое double rounding error](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593141/Что-такое-double-rounding-error-ошибка-двойного-округления), на всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо, убрал f из входного значения и все заиграло.